# how to change the color of the tabbar controller

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way I can change the Tab Bar Controller's color to something other than the default black? I know this isn't possible in IB, but perhaps maybe through code?

Answer (score 2):

In AppDelegate

```
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

In AppDelegate.m in didFinishLaunching... method write(this will change for whole app):

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor myColor]];
```

Or you can write in ViewController.m in method viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor mycolor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with XIB/Storyboard as well as programmatically 
For Xib/storyboard select tab bar controller than tab and you can see all the options to change tab bar or tab bar view properties see the attached image [Image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q04Ra.png)

For programmatically:
for tab bar tint and background

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:panelColor];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```